# Getting the active form caption color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, appearance

How can i get the color of the caption of the active form in winforms?

(Without Api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SystemColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx) class contains [a number of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors_properties.aspx) corresponding to various system colors. The one you want is [`SystemColors.ActiveCaption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.activecaption.aspx).